# Woocommerce autocomplete postalcode field

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, autocomplete, woocommerce

How to make the Postcode field in woocommerce checkout page make a suggestion based on list (zip01, zip02, zip03) when the user start typing the field. Just like jqueryui autocomplete.

```
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] = array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'class' => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
    'validate' => array( 'postcode' ),
    'autocomplete' => 'postal-code',
    'options' => array( 'zip01'=>'zip01', 'zip02'=>'zip02'),
    'required' => true
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [WP dev doc: including css javascript](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) the Jquery Autocomplete UI already registered in the default wordpress script, I only need to call it:

This code goes to **function.php** on the theme folder:

```
// Load ui.autocomplete javascript and style
 function add_theme_scripts() { 
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-base', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css', false,'1.0','all');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'resource.zip', get_theme_file_uri() . '/js/resource.zip.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' ),'1.1',true);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

This is the **resource.zip.js**:

```
( function( $ ) {
    var availableZip = [
        'ZIP01',
        'ZIP02',
        'ZIP03'
    ];
    $( "#billing_postcode" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableZip,
      select: function (event, ui) {
        $( "#billing_postcode" ).val( ui.item.value );
        jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        return false;
      }
    });
    $( "#billing_postcode" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        return false;
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

Found the js target function trigger for shipping cost update is 'update_checkout'. This code works for me, it tested on desktop with mouse, keyboard and device with touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the source of your options is in PHP, you can create that options for the input using a `datalist` html element...

```
<input list="zipcodeoptions" name="zipcode">

<datalist id="zipcodeoptions">
    <?php
    foreach($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['options'] as $key => $value)
        echo "<option value=\"".$value."\">";
    ?>
</datalist>
```

**EDITED**:

Ok, so you have to do it in Woocommerce... After reading your link, I think on option is override `billing_postcode` to turn it into a select hooking into the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter...

```
// Hook in
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields');

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {

    // Just changing what is needed to turn it into a select.
    // Modify other options if you need.
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['options'] = array('zip01' => "zip01",
                                                              'zip02' => "zip02",
                                                              'zip03' => "zip03");

    return $fields;
}
```

Or if you want to do it for both, billing and shipping address, you can hook into `woocommerce_default_address_fields`...

```
// Hook in
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields','custom_override_default_address_fields');

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields($address_fields) {

    // Just changing what is needed to turn it into a select.
    // Modify other options if you need.
    $address_fields['postcode']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['postcode']['options'] = array('zip01' => "zip01",
                                                   'zip02' => "zip02",
                                                   'zip03' => "zip03");

    return $address_fields;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, but it need to be written in wordpress and woocommerce manner. I know this much: [tutorial customising checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters).

Comment: I see... I don't know Woocommerce, but check the edited answer to see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I've tried that, it will render the Postcode field in <select> type, but it broke the jquery event listener that update the shipping cost. The shipping cost should adjust automatically based on the zipcode.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only work when you have bootstrap with your theme.

Comment: I can find a bootstrap.min.css in the source but how do I know for sure it build on bootstrap framework?